# How to know mouseDragged direction - when it's up or down?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

Finishing to create custom scrollbar, and the question is:

```
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

        //How to know mouse direction - up or down?

    }
});
```

Maybe there is some simple method, or I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do it manually but you will need a `MouseAdapter` instead of a `MouseMotionAdapter` to record the initial Y co-ordinate.

```
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    int previousY;

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        previousY = e.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

        int y = e.getY();
        if (y < previousY) {
            System.out.println("UP");
        } else if (y > previousY) {
            System.out.println("DOWN");
        }

        previousY = y;
    }
});
```

Comment: You should initialise the y position in mousePressed, as MouseInfo is relative to the screen, not the component that generated the event, this could cause a false direction oni the first mouseDragged event ;)

Comment: In my situation `e.getYOnScreen();` was usefull, and scrollbar is contrlled by the difference `y - previousY`. Almost finished :)